# Xdebug Auto Step Out

Tags: php, codeigniter, visual-studio-code, xdebug

I am using Xdebug inside my VSCode for my application written using CodeIgniter Framework, I was wondering if there is an option to auto Step Out (do not display) the part that happens inside CodeIgniter core.

In other words, does VSCode -> Xdebug support a feature where I can put specific path for auto Step Over?